# Freezing the max heap space option

Tags: java, jvm, java-6, jvm-arguments

Is there any way to hide the options `-Xmx` and `-Xmx` from user? I mean don't let the user play with the java heap size. Set a X amount of max/min heap size for all the Java app.

I tried to find some kind of JVM config setting, but couldn't get. Is there a way to handle this? Or shall I look in JDK code and change the `-Xmx/s` option?

I am running java on linux based board.

Please suggest.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: I don't want user to play with the device heap memory and create memory issue for other apps to starve.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to hide the options -Xmx and -Xmx from user?

Not if the user has direct access to the `java` command and to your class file / JAR files.

If you can run the game on a system where the user cannot run `java` directly, you can either create an uneditable "shortcut" to launch your game, or write a wrapper or a custom Java launcher that removed the user's ability to pass certain options.

Maybe it would be simpler to have your Java app look at the `java` command-line options and check for options that mess with the heap settings in ways that are undesirable.

Warning: each of these approaches can be subverted by someone with moderate reverse engineering skills.